# Unable to send data to POST Service in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, rest, post

I'm trying to write a simple HTTP REST service using Spring 4.

I'm having troubles sending data to a POST endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/onlyPost", produces = "application/json", method 
= RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestParam("value1") 
String param1, @RequestParam("value2") String param2) {
....
}
```

While trying to send data with Postman, I receive a 400 message (obviously the values are setted in the request's body)

```
"message": "Required String parameter 'value1' is not present",
```

What I have noticed is that the issue is somewhat related to the headers, because when I remove the postman's header (**Content-Type: application/json**) everything works fine.

I tried for more than one hour fixing this by myself with no results. Any hints?

Comment: `@RequestParam` is used to read query parameters from a URL, it does not read JSON fields.

Comment: Well, what do you *want* to do? If you want to send a JSON object as the body of the request, then you shouldn't have any RequestParam. You should have `@RequestBody SomeClassMappedToJson` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestParam` is used to read a URL query parameter.

```
http://localhost:8080/springmvc/onlyPost?value1=foo&value2=bar
```

For instance, in the URL above, `value1` and `value2` are query parameters that you can read using that annotation.

But if you want to read a JSON request instead, you need to change the method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/onlyPost", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    ....
}
```

where User is a POJO holding the two fields:

```
public class User {
    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve the problem after following this answer and adding the @ JsonCreator and @ JsonProperty in the POJO class.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP 400` is returned when your request is badly formatted, i.e. missing required request parameters

`@RequestParam` is for URL Params, if you want to pass them like that, you call
`<api_url>/onlyPost?value1=<value1>&value2=<value2>`
but... if you want to create user you should rather use `@RequestBody` and put your user data there. Something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", produces = "application/json", method 
= RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    [...]
}
```

if you are creating REST api you should use concrete endpoints, here is a pretty cool reading with some tips: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Comment: The question code was a sample one, I voluntarily changed endpoint names and variable names. Thanks anyway for the link, pretty interesting lecture :)